# Is it possible to store Thunderbird's passwords in GNOME keyring?

Tags: thunderbird, password, gnome-keyring

Currently Thunderbird has its own password manager, but it offers two possibilities: either you don't encrypt the password stored, or you use another password to encrypt the actual one for e-mail. This sounds quite useless to me, so I would prefer to store Thunderbird passwords in GNOME keyring. Hope this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension called [GNOME Keyring integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/thunderbird/addon/mozilla-gnome-keyring/).

Answer (score 1):

Have not yet tried it but: https://github.com/infinity0/mozilla-gnome-keyring#readme

Comment: It does work but may be a bit hard to compile unless your OS works with the default Makefile. Here's my variant for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS + Thunderbird 10.0.2: https://github.com/mikkorantalainen/firefox-gnome-keyring

Comment: It does work for me too so far, though even for Oneiric I could not find it in binary form and it took some work to compile. https://github.com/mdlavin/firefox-gnome-keyring/issues/4 has some information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, looks like it is not possible in the latest Firefox/Thunderbird versions any longer. Refer to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1321508 for more information.